# Coverity Static Analysis Saying Unsigned Int is Char (C++)

Tags: c++, unsigned-integer, coverity

I am using Coverity to statically analyze some of our source code for a C++ project. I realize this may seem like a ridiculously simple question, but I figured if Coverity has an issue like this I want to know the underlying reason why this error is flagged. It keeps flagging an error and I want to know if this error is really something to change my coding practices for or if it is really unnecessary.

An example of the error it flags is:

```
unsigned int a;
a = 5;
```

Coverity has an issue with this and says:

"CID 101436 (#1 of 1): Implicit integer conversion (MISRA_CAST)
integer_signedness_changing_conversion: MISRA-2004 Rule 10.1 violation: implicitly changing the signedness of an expression. Converting 5, with underlying type char (8 bits, signed), to type unsigned int (32 bits, unsigned) with different signedness."

Won't any modern compiler know that in the example above the 5 is an unsigned int and not a char? Is this really a valid error and could it ever cause errors with compilation?
The error will go away as soon as I add:

```
unsigned int a;
a = 5U;
```

Is it really an issue if I don't specify the "U" after every unsigned int?

Comment: No, this is obviously not an issue. Why are you following MISRA to begin with?

Comment: The error is right and wrong.  It is wrong ion that `5` is a int as that is the smallest integer literal.  It is right though that `5` can be used to initialize a `char` without issue as its known to be in the valid range that `char` can hold.

Comment: If you want the warnings about signed types to go away, either append a 'U' or modify the checkers in Coverity (disable the checker).

Comment: We are using MISRA because it is software for embedded systems.

Comment: The MISRA marmite rules. The compiler will perform an implicit conversion, but MISRA considers this unsafe. Embedded systems are so varied, and that obscures the reasons (usually historical) behind many MISRA rules. You may be writing for an 8 bit micro with 256 bytes of RAM, dubious endianness and a "proprietary" implementation; then you'll really appreciate MISRA. Many of the problems MISRA tries to prevent though, are already being prevented by modern compilers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, numeric integral constants without suffixes are signed quantities.  You will either need to cast the constant or append the 'U' suffix.

The other issue is that constants are assigned the smallest type that will contain the value.  For example, 5 fits into a `int8_t` or `signed char`.  However, 260 is too big for a `signed char`, so its minimum type is `int`.

The second warning may go away after the signedness issue is resolved.

Comment: So without the U suffix, the compiler will interpret the 5 as a char? It has to know that it is being assigned to an unsigned int right and automatically resolve to that type right? I am just wondering why this MISRA rule exists if modern compilers obviously have no issue with this sort of thing.

Comment: You need to get a copy of the MISRA C-2004 and look up section "6.10.4 Underlying type".  Too much text to paste in the answer.

Comment: You can find some related issues by searching the internet for "stackoverflow MISRA C"